# Export blender design to OpenGL ES 1.1

Tags: android, opengl-es, blender

I'm developing and Android application.

I have a model on Blender and I want to export it to use it with OpenGL ES 1.1. on Android.

How can I export my model as a set of points and vertex?

Is there any other suitable format to use with OpenGL ES 1.1? I'm not using a rendering engine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Wavefront (.obj) for your export, and put it into the assets directory of your project.  There are a few different .obj importers with sample code available on the web. One of them is from Earth Live Wallpaper [here](http://code.google.com/p/earth-live-wallpaper/source/browse/trunk/%20earth-live-wallpaper/SLWP/src/com/seb/SLWP/Sphere.java).

From studying the code, it looks to me like the index buffer is unnecessary, and the Earth Wallpaper could just be using draw arrays instead of draw buffers, because none of the vertices are reused.

I suppose you could expand on this code to identify identical vertices and merge them, but it might slow down the load time a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As @TenFour04 Mentions, **.obj** is a good option. Have a look at Dennis Ippel's tutorial on [loading 3D models with the min3D framework](http://www.rozengain.com/blog/2010/05/17/loading-3d-models-with-the-min3d-framework-for-android/).

Answer (score 0):

You could also export them to Collada and use android's colada loader somewhere from google projects. This is far from complete though.

Answer (score 0):

You also can refer to badlogic libgdx examples.

Comment: Where are these? Please expand your answer